# Splitting the dictionary into multiple copies in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary

```
d = {
    'facets':{'style':"collared",'pocket':"yes"},   
    'vars':[    {'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"XL"}}, 
                {'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"L"}}   ]
}
```

Since there are 2 dictionaries in 'vars' key, i want to have 3 different dictionaries as given below. Please make it dynamically 3 documents as the the 'vars' can have any number of facets

```
d1 = {
    'facets':{'style':"collared",'pocket':"yes"}
} 
d2 = {
    'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"XL"}
}
d3 = {
    'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"L"}
}
```

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Don't name variables sequentially. Use a list instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create separate variables. If you have 3 additional facet dictionaries in the `vars` key, you have to figure out how to create `d4` as well, etc. Later on you suddenly have to now guess at how many `d*` variables exist.

Create a list instead:

```
facets = [{'facets': d['facets']}] + [facet for facet in d['vars']]
```

With a list, you can now simply loop over all the `facets` entries to manipulate or display them.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {
...     'facets':{'style':"collared",'pocket':"yes"},
...     'vars':[    {'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"XL"}},
...                 {'facets':{'color':"blue", 'size':"L"}}   ]
... }
>>> [{'facets': d['facets']}] + [facet for facet in d['vars']]
[{'facets': {'pocket': 'yes', 'style': 'collared'}}, {'facets': {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'XL'}}, {'facets': {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'L'}}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[{'facets': {'pocket': 'yes', 'style': 'collared'}},
 {'facets': {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'XL'}},
 {'facets': {'color': 'blue', 'size': 'L'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the basic would be somthing like:

```
d1 = {k: v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k!= 'vars'}
other_ds = [ d1.copy().update(var) for var in d['vars'] ]
```

But you can modify to get exactly what you want, like:

```
d2 = d1.copy().update(d['vars'][0])
```

or (since python 3.5)

```
d2 = {**d1, **d['vars'][0]}
```

Or whatever combination you feel it's easier to understand.

Comment: Edit *(k,v) in d* to *k,v in d.items()*

Comment: Why copy `d1` at all? There are no values shared between the dictionaries produced. And what if there are more than two additional facets in `'vars'`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I assumed there are more than just `'facets'` in the dictionary and that a merge is required. But, if that's not the case, you're right, we can skip the copy.

Comment: The OP under-specified; give them the simplest thing that provides their expected output without trying to second guess.  Your solution is way overkill without any evidence that it is needed.